# Nhibernate subsequent read after stored procedure call

Tags: c#, nhibernate, ado, second-level-cache

I have a strange behaviour of NHibernate and ADO.NET. I'm using NHibernate as standard ORM but some operation are faster with ADO.NET (like batch or calling a stored procedure).

So I'm doing the following

```
var item = _items.GetById(100);
```

Then I do call a stored procedure that do update the same entity with the following instructions

```
 var session = _sessionManager.OpenSession();
 using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
 {
      var item = _items.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemCode == code);

      var cmd = session.Connection.CreateCommand();
      session.Transaction.Enlist(cmd);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      SqlParameter id = SQLUtil.GetParam("@bigId", SqlDbType.BigInt, inout: false);

      cmd.CommandText = "storedUpdateItem";
      cmd.Parameters.Add(SQLUtil.GetParam("@tstTS", SqlDbType.Timestamp, inout: false));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(id);

      int ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      if (ret != 1)
      {
          throw new ApplicationException("Something gone wrong with update");
      } 
      tx.Commit();

      return _items.GetById(id.Value);
}
```

So the last operation to retrieve again using a NHibernate repository patter the item. The problem is that the item is not update with the database. It seems to be the previous version. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can force NHibernate to refresh the cached version of `item` by using the `Refresh` method of the `session` object:

```
      ...
      var item = _items.GetById(id.Value);
      session.Refresh(item);
      return item;
}
```